# Select Column where 3 rows contain separate values - Self Join?

Tags: mysql

Looking for the best method to perform a select statement. I think a SELF JOIN is best approach, but I'm having trouble putting it together. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

I have a table of item meta:

```
+----------+----------+-------+
| item_num | field_id | meta  |
+----------+----------+-------+
|      800 |      508 | red   |
|      800 |      507 | shirt |
|      800 |      504 | 2     |
|      700 |      508 | red   |
|      700 |      507 | shirt |
|      700 |      504 | 3     |
|      500 |      508 | red   |
|      500 |      507 | shirt |
|      500 |      504 | 5     |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

Select item_num from table WHERE:

1. field_id=508 AND meta=red
2. field_id=507 AND meta=shirt
3. field_id=504 AND meta=2

My initial statement idea:

```
SELECT   a.item_num
FROM     Table a
  JOIN   Table b
  JOIN   Table c
      ON a.item_num = b.item_num = c.item_num
     AND a.field_id = 508
     AND a.meta = red
     AND b.field_id = 507
     AND b.meta = shirt
     AND c.field_id = 504
     AND c.meta = 2
GROUP BY a.item_num
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What results do you expect?

Comment: As Raymond said, it really is not clear what you want the result to look like. Please try to show an example of expected result to make it easier to help you.

Comment: I want to get "item_num", if it exists.  I'm going to use the "item_num" for editing the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is easier using group by

```
 SELECT item_num
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY item_num
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN field_id=508 AND meta='red' THEN 1 END) > 0
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN field_id=507 AND meta='shirt' THEN 1 END) > 0
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN field_id=504 AND meta='2' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Also can be written as

```
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN field_id=508 AND meta='red'   THEN 1 
                   WHEN field_id=507 AND meta='shirt' THEN 1 
                   WHEN field_id=504 AND meta='2'     THEN 1 
              END) = 3
```

Comment: And for the field_id 507 and 504?

Comment: Thanks Juan.  I'm trying it out now.